# Python Pandas Desktop RAM crashing when processing a big file (>600 MB) and doing groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing a big CSV file (>600 MB) using Pandas.
And doing several group by to get frequency stats on various variables in the dataset (Similar to PROC FREQ in SAS). But Pandas is hanging the system down. The memory RAM usage (by Python) is shooting up to 4 GB.

I have other columns also (like amount, date, etc) on which i want to enable stats.

Is there a way that Pandas do not Load to memory and instead processes them in disk, so the system performance doesnt hog down ? 
Or any suggestions to process efficiently would be great ?

Code below:

```
colNamesOutputFile=["PROGRAM_NAME", "TEST_GROUP", "NAME", "OFFER"]
inputDF=pd.read_csv(InputFile
, skiprows=1
, names=colNamesOutputFile
, converters={'PROGRAM_NAME': convert_to_string, 'TEST_GROUP': convert_to_string, 'NAME': convert_to_string, 'OFFER': convert_to_string}
, index_col=False)
inputDF1SUM = pd.DataFrame({'Count' : inputDF.groupby(['PROGRAM_NAME','TEST_GROUP']).size()}).reset_index()
inputDF2SUM = pd.DataFrame(inputDF.groupby('NAME')).reset_index()
inputDF3SUM = pd.DataFrame(inputDF.groupby('OFFER')).reset_index()
print(inputDF1SUM)
print(inputDF2SUM)
print(inputDF3SUM)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the csv in chunks, for each chunk you can do your process and move to the next chunk, this way you don't load too much into the memory.

```
chunksize = 10 ** 4
pieces = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    process(chunk)
    pieces.extend([chunk.groupby(['PROGRAM_NAME','TEST_GROUP'])])
```

You can read more in [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

All this is assuming you do not need the entire dataset in memory all at one time.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. Have one question though, will i still be able to use the groupby ...i guess have to loop and keep adding the groupby summary variables

Comment: @sutirmukherjee , Iv'e updated my code at the answer, you can do something like this.

Comment: If reading into chunks don't fulfill your purpose, then you should try dask